# MediatR is returning null while unit testing controller

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api, nunit, mediatr

I am trying to unit test my controller but I am using MediatR. I have mocked it but somehow result is null. I tried to search other people questions but non of them helped.

My controller:

```
[HttpGet("{authorId}")]
    [ProducesResponseType(200, Type = typeof(Author))]
    [ProducesResponseType(400)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetAuthor(int authorId)
    {
        var query = new GetAuthorQuery(authorId);
        var result = await _mediator.Send(query); 
        return result != null ? (IActionResult)Ok(result) : NotFound();
    }
```

Unit Test constructor:

```
private Mock<IMediator> _mediator;
 public BookStoreAuthorControllerTests()
    {
        _mediator= new Mock<IMediator>();
        _authorRepository= new Mock<IAuthorRepository>();
        fixture= new Fixture();

        fixture.Behaviors.OfType<ThrowingRecursionBehavior>().ToList()
        .ForEach(b => fixture.Behaviors.Remove(b));
        fixture.Behaviors.Add(new OmitOnRecursionBehavior());

        var mapperConfig = new MapperConfiguration(c =>
        {
            c.AddProfile<Helpers.MappingProfiles>();
        });
        _mapper = mapperConfig.CreateMapper();

    }
```

GetAuthor Test :

```
 [Test]
    public async Task GetAuthor_Returns_Ok()
    {
        var author = fixture.Build<Author>().Create();
        var mappedAuthor= _mapper.Map<AuthorDto>(author);

        var controller = new AuthorController(_mediator.Object);
        var query = new GetAuthorQuery(author.Id);

        _authorRepository.Setup(r=>r.GetAuthor(author.Id)).ReturnsAsync(author);
        _mediator.Setup(x => x.Send(query, It.IsAny<CancellationToken>())).ReturnsAsync(mappedAuthor);

        var result = await controller.GetAuthor(author.Id);
        var obj = result as ObjectResult;

        Assert.AreEqual(200, obj.StatusCode);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in the mocking of that `Send` method, shown below.

```csharp
_mediator.Setup(
    x => x.Send(query, It.IsAny<CancellationToken>())
    ).ReturnsAsync(mappedAuthor);
```

Given that the `query` variable is a `GetAuthorQuery` `class`/reference type, makes that is not the exact same instance that gets passed at runtime. Because of that, the mock doesn't execute the `ReturnsAsync` method in order to return the given `Author` object.

2 possible ways to solve this; do one of below.

1. Set up the mock using `It.IsAny<GetAuthorQuery>()` instead of `query`.

```csharp
_mediator.Setup(
     x => x.Send(It.IsAny<GetAuthorQuery>(),  It.IsAny<CancellationToken>())
     ).ReturnsAsync(mappedAuthor);
```

2. Define that `GetAuthorQuery` as a `record` instead of a `class`; `record` types use [value equality](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/records#value-equality). Doing so you can keep using that `query` variable in your mock setup

```csharp
public record GetAuthorQuery : IRequest<Author>
```

Comment: Very clear answer @pfx . Thanks a lot.